# I want to state the fact based on the data I have

Tags: sentence-construction

I have recorded the variation in the prices for a particular snack
in the supermarket nearby.   Here are some data:

> 6 Jan: 2.15
>   12 March: 2.21
>   25 June: 2.35

I will check the new price in August, now I am trying to guess the new price based on the above data, and I have written this sentence:

> The variation in the prices for my favourite snack is not steady. I guess the new price for the snack will be bounded by 2.5 by the early August.

This is my first time trying to write a sentence this way. Is my sentence completely understandable?

Comment: When you say **bounded by** do you mean that it won't exceed 2.50? P.S. "by early August" without **the**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're using *past* data to *extrapolate* future prices?  I'm not sure how you arrive at 2.5, but that's not really important:

> The *increase* in the price of X has been *steady* but *inconsistent*.  I *estimate* that the price will *rise* to 2.5 by early August.

The key word here is "estimate", since that is the essence of what you are doing.  Another example:

> Although the price of gasoline is usually higher in the summer, I *estimate* that this year prices will remain low due to oversupply.

If you are using statistical analysis then you will want to include some relevant terms like "average" (or "mean"), "standard deviation", and so on.